# Highlight html column with minimum value with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to highlight a column (or just a header title) which has the lowest value.
The code below I can find de lowest value, but I don't know how to find and highlight the column of lowest value.

```js
$(function(){
 var values = $('.total').map(function() {
  return parseInt( $(this).html().replace("$ ","") );
 }).get();

 var minimum = Math.min.apply( null, values );
 
 alert(minimum);
})
```

```css
.better-price{
    background-color: #ff7f50;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 100px;">Product</th>
            <th style="width: 100px;">Quantity</th>
            <th style="width: 100px;" id="company_1">Company 1</th>
            <th style="width: 100px;" id="company_2">Company 2</th>
         <th style="width: 100px;" id="company_3">Company 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Product 1</td>
   <td>5 m</td>
   <td>$ 10.00</td>
   <td>$ 50.00</td>
   <td>$ 50.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Product 2</td>
   <td>5 m</td>
   <td>$ 20.00</td>
   <td>$ 40.00</td>
   <td>$ 40.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Product 3</td>
   <td>50 m2</td>
   <td>$ 30.00</td>
   <td>$ 30.00</td>
   <td>$ 30.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Product 4</td>
   <td>2 Un</td>
   <td>$ 40.00</td>
   <td>$ 20.00</td>
   <td>$ 20.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Product 5</td>
   <td>1 Un</td>
   <td>$ 50.00</td>
   <td>$ 10.00</td>
   <td>$ 20.00</td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label>Total</label></td>
   <td><label>$ 150.00</label></td>
   <td><label>$ 150.00</label></td>
   <td><label>$ 150.00</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label>Shipping amount</label></td>
   <td><label>$ 100.00</label></td>
   <td><label>$ 99.00</label></td>
   <td><label>$ 99.00</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><label>Total + shipping</label></td>
   <td class="total">$ 250.00</td>
   <td class="total">$ 249.00</td>
   <td class="total">$ 259.00</td>
        </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><label>Valid until</label></td>
   <td><label>2015/01/01</label></td>
   <td><label>2015/01/01</label></td>
   <td><label>2015/01/01</label></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
   <td>
    <button>Select</button>
   </td>
   <td>
    <button>Select</button>
   </td>
   <td>
    <button>Select</button>
   </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any ideias how can I hightlight the column or title?

Comment: It might be easier to do the calculation on the server side (if you can) and decorate with a class that way.  Otherwise, I think you need to write a javascript function to parse the table and determine the parent column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through each of the totals and then add the class to the minimum

```
$(function(){
    var values = $('.total').map(function() {
        return parseInt( $(this).html().replace("$ ","") );
    }).get();

    var minimum = Math.min.apply( null, values );

    $('.total').each(function(){
        if(parseInt( $(this).html().replace("$ ","")) == minimum){ 
            $(this).addClass('better-price');
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for help. Your code works! I just made a correction in the second function. You need to add parseInt on $(this).html().replace("$ ","") to compare with mininum value.

Comment: @TiagoCrizanto please mark the correct answer for future users.

Comment: this is not the right answer... the question was to highlight the column... not to highlight the cell...

Comment: @LeoJavier I chosed this answer because your solution isn't dynamic. The "limit" variable reive fixed value. In the message I sad that I need highlight a column or the header title. The answer of Pindo is dynamic and if the table has n columns js code will highligh the cell with minimun value.

Comment: it is dynamic! it is actually making sure you can have unlimited rows and the script still highlighting the (whole column) not just the cell... your table has a different configuration - (All the rows are 5 columns) but in the last 5 rows are just (4 columns). The limit variable is just making sure that even the configuration is different in the last 5 columns the (whole column)  with the lowest value still getting the css class... otherwise it would jump one column...   but is ok man, I missed when you said "or just a header title" :) at the end we are here to help eachother

Comment: Sorry Pindo, your answer is valid!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/leojavier/y4wxf8dv/1/

```
$(function(){
    var el;
    var values = $('.total').map(function() {
        el = $(this);
        return parseInt( $(this).html().replace("$ ","") );

    }).get();

    var minimum = Math.min.apply( null, values );
    var i = 1;
    var index = el.parent().context.cellIndex;
    var limit = $('tr').length - 5;

    $('tr').each(function(){
        if(i<limit) {
        $('tr:nth-child('+i+')').find('td:nth-child('+parseInt(index+1) +')').addClass('better-price');
        }else{
        $('tr:nth-child('+i+')').find('td:nth-child('+ index+')').addClass('better-price');
        }
        i++
    });

})
```